# Cake php Sub Folder Installation, Temp folder errors from htaccess or file permissions?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, file-permissions, subdirectory

My client has asked for a cake php app i've made for them to go into a sub directory on their existing server. 
All works perfectly on my test remote and local installations.

Initially I had a problem with htaccess and had to add RewriteBase /quotesystem/ to my htaccess files in order to see the site at all.  So I have changed my htaccess as below:

cake root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /quotesystem/
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

app .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /quotesystem/app/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

and webroot .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /quotesystem/app/webroot/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I can access my site but i get loads of warnings about the temp directory:

Warning (2): SplFileInfo::openFile(/web/sites/_p/_e/_t/petersen-stainless.co.uk/public/www/quotesystem/app/tmp/cache/persistent/cake_core_cake_en-gb) [function.SplFileInfo-openFile]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory [CORE/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 295]

You can see it here: http://www.petersen-stainless.co.uk/quotesystem

Now, i've CHMOD the temp directory to 777 so everyone should have permissions but i still get these errors.

I've deleted all of the files in these folders so that the temp directories have been cleaned.

When I use my ftp client - transmit - to look at the file permissions the owner appears as (?) and if i try to change it i get an error:
Could not change owner of “tmp”. Server said: 'SITE CHOWN' not understood

I dont get this with any other site I work on.

I don't understand enough to know what is going on, is this a permissions problem or an .htaccess problem or both?  Or is it a server configuration problem?

If anyone can help shed some light on this and help my understanding i'd be very grateful.

**UPDATE:**
My directory structure on the server is as follows:

-- public

--- www

----- quotesystem

------- lib

------- app

--------- config

--------- webroot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the SplFileInfo warning appears when Cake attempts to read/write cache that it does not have permission to access.  Make sure your application has permission to read/write the cache/tmp folder (depending on your Cake version).

Comment: and that the tmp folder structure exists (app tmp _cache_ - especially given " No such file or directory " in the error message) +1.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a .htaccess problem. The `RewriteBase` should be the same for both the `webroot` and `app` .htaccess. So the line in both files should be:

```
RewriteBase /quotesystem/
```

I personally never touch the .htaccess in the Cake root directory as it doesn't seem to be necessary to alter anything there.

In addition, `/tmp/cache` and it's subdirectories should be writable as well.

Comment: thanks for the reply but that doesn't seem to change anything.  I tried all combinations with no luck.  By webroot did you mean the sub folder cake is in (quotesystem) or the app>webroot folder?  I don't usually touch this either because i dont usually have to! however on this server it is required...

Comment: Yes, I meant `app/webroot`. I think you're definitely having issues with mod_rewrite as some of the images fail to load as well. This file: `http://www.petersen-stainless.co.uk/quotes/img/twitter_icon.png` is present in `app/webroot/img/`, right?

Comment: Hmmm, seems they are just linked incorrectly, as `http://www.petersen-stainless.co.uk/quotesystem/img/twitter_icon.png` does exist. Also,`/tmp/cache`, `/tmp/cache/persistent` and `/tmp/cache/models` should be writable as well.

Comment: Hi yeah you are right about the images, on my local and test installations /img/twitter_icon.png is enough but on this server they need to have the sub directory prepended in order to be found.  This makes me think it is an .htaccess issue to.  All temp sub folders are writeable with 777 too.  I've tried some different re-write bases with no luck.  If i take the rewrite base out i just get a 404 so it must be correct?

Comment: would the main site root directory containing the quotesystem cake folder need an .htaccesss file?

Comment: I don't think so, you could try and remove it temporarily. If that doesn't resolve things the path of the RewriteBase could also be incorrect, but for me to know for certain you would have to update your question with the way your directories are set up.

Comment: I've also just noticed that changing the rewrite base for quotesystem/app and quotesystem/app/webroot makes no difference.  In fact if i remove the rewrite rules from these two files altogether it seems to matter.  I'm getting desperately confused here...

Comment: I've added the directory structure to the original question.  thanks for your help!

Comment: Judging from the directory layout you've posted you don't need the `RewriteBase` directive set. This is only necessary when the Cake core and the app directory are in separate locations. As for your problem, are you certain the directories in `/tm` have the correct permissions?

Comment: certain, all the temp folders and files are 777.  however, as i said I can't see the owner and CHOWN is not working.  I removed the rewrite base and instead added the folder to the re-write rules, for example: RewriteRule    ^$ /quotesystem/app/webroot/    [L]  that works the same.

Comment: Are there files in the subdirectories of the cache directory? If so you should remove them. If not, it could very well be a ownership (CHOWN) issue.

Comment: There are no files in the any of the temp directories.  I already tried that and cleared them all out.